# quarterly difference in sum(Revenue) saved in a new column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, difference

I need to add a new column to my table that will have the difference between sum of revenue of a new quarter over the last one.
My data looks like this:

```
Website       Year          Quarter          Revenue
cosmo.com      2019           4               10
cosmo.com      2020           1               15
cosmo.com      2020           2               5
fashion.com    2019           4               10
fashion.com    2020           1               5
fashion.com    2020           2               20
```

The desired output is:

```
Website       Year          Quarter          Revenue         Difference
cosmo.com      2019           4               10                +5
cosmo.com      2020           1               15                +5
cosmo.com      2020           2               5                 -10
fashion.com    2019           4               10                +10
fashion.com    2020           1               5                 -5
fashion.com    2020           2               20                +15
```

I have tried to see the yearly difference, to begin with, but got a syntax error

```
select *,
`Revenue` - lag(`Revenue`) over(order by `Year`) as difference 
from table`
```

Comment: Where does the initial +5 come from?

Comment: You are missing a comma after *

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want the difference from the previous *quarter*, not *year*.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (t.Revenue - lag(t.Revenue) over (partition by website order by Year, quarter)) as difference 
from table t;
```

Note the use of `partition by` for the website.